# How to pass parameters into __init__ function

Tags: python, excel, arguments

I am starting my journey in python. I want to create a program that will convert my xlsx file into an sql file and then load data into a data base.

I want to create class that will have two parameters:

- ex - will open xlsx workbook
- sh - will open sheet from ex with correct index

This is initial version (for now I am just printing rows):

```
class XToSql():
    def __init__(self, ex = xlrd.open_workbook('ex1.xlsx'), sh = ex.sheet_by_index(0)):
        self.ex = ex
        self.sh = sh

    def modify(self):
        for i in str((self.sh.nrows-1)):
            a = 1
            print(self.sh.row_values(a))
            a += 1

a1 = XToSql()
a1.modify()
```

In the `__init__` function, this line is marked with red color: `sh = ex.sheet_by_index(0) ->` and this error appears after Run: 
`def __init__(self, ex = xlrd.open_workbook('ex1.xlsx'), sh = ex.sheet_by_index(0)):`

```
NameError: name 'ex' is not defined
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix the indentation. - Select all the code and type `ctrl-k`. [Markdown Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `__init__`'s parameter list, `ex` has not been evaluated yet so `sh = ex.sheet_by_index(0))` is throwing the NameError.  This happens when the class object is being created.

You can do a couple of things. One reason to write a class is so you can reuse it, so maybe the class should only except the filepath as an argument.

```
class XToSql():

    def __init__(self, ex_file):

        self.ex = xlrd.open_workbook(ex_file)
        self.sh = self.ex.sheet_by_index(0)

    def modify(self):
        for i in str(self.sh.nrows - 1):
            a = 1
            print(self.sh.row_values(a))
            a += 1
```

Maybe you should be able to specify the sheet to process

```
class XToSql():

    def __init__(self, ex_file, sheet=0):

        self.ex = xlrd.open_workbook(ex_file)
        self.sh = self.ex.sheet_by_index(sheet))

    def modify(self):
        for i in str(self.sh.nrows - 1):
            a = 1
            print(self.sh.row_values(a))
            a += 1
```

And use it like this

```
a = XToSql(ex_file='ex1.xlsx', sheet=0)
```

Comment: In both your `__init__` methods the line `ex.sheet_by_index( ... ` won't make sense. What is `ex`?

Comment: Thnx - fixed (had a few things)

Comment: After fix it is working. Thx
__init__ and self is still magic for me :)

Answer (score 2):

`ex` is not available until inside the body of the `__init__` method. You cannot access an argument of the method outside the body of the method.

You would need to do something like the following:

```
class XToSql:
    def __init__(self, ex, sh=None):
        self.ex = ex
        if sh is None:
            sh = ex.sheet_by_index(0)
        self.sh = sh
```

And then call it like this:

```
a1 = XToSql(xlrd.open_workbook('ex1.xlsx'))
```